# Segmentation fault while returning a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

So this is code for inserting a new element into a linked list. It takes the address of the first node and the integer data to be inserted. But I'm getting Segfault when I return the address of the first node back. I've read other similar questions but there the OP was returning a pointer to a local variable. Here, I'm actually returning a local pointer.

```
 struct Node
 {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
 }
 Node* Insert(Node *head,int data)
 {   
    Node* temp=head;
    Node* return_value=temp;
    cout<<head<<"  ";
    while(temp!=NULL && temp->next!=NULL)
    {
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    Node new_obj;
    if(temp==NULL)
    {
        temp=&new_obj;
        temp->data=data;
        cout<<temp<<" "<<temp->data<<" ";
        return(temp);
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't even compile.

Comment: You are returning the address of new_obj which ceases to exist after the call to Insert()

Comment: Thanks. But how do I return the new address? Because creating a new object seems the only way if the list is empty.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages, and the possible solutions to your problem depend on which you are using.  Apparently that is C++.  Edit your tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Node new_obj` makes an object on the stack, not the heap.  That object ceases to exist when `Insert` exits.  You want `temp = new Node;` rather than `temp=&new_obj;`.

**Edit** Also, if the list is nonempty, your `while` loop will leave `temp` pointing to the non-NULL last node of the list.  Therefore, you won't actually allocate a new node because the `if(temp==NULL)` check will fail!

**Edit 2** The `return temp;` is fine just the way it is.  To fix the segfault, only the creation of the new node needs to change.  For the `while` bug, there are lots of ways to fix it.  One option is to look up information about "header nodes" for lists.  Another is to test for `head==NULL` first and handle that separately.

Comment: That was so dumb of me. I completely overlooked that part. Thanks a lot. But, if I want to return the address of the new node created, how can I do that? Also, this is just half the program just for the empty list case.

Comment: @JayParkeh, in that case be so kind to do the following: (1) accept the answer. (2) edit your question's code so it can compile. Thanks

Comment: @JayParekh Glad to help!  Answer edited per your comment.  If this answer solved your problem, would you please hit the checkmark to accept it, as user3078414 noted?  See the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more about the flow here.  When you accept, the question will be removed from the "unanswered" lists, and we will both get reputation points :)

Comment: Hi! Accepted your answer. So about the segfault, instead of creating a new object, I did an malloc for temp and returned it. It worked. And thanks for the help about the loop but like I said, it was just a part of the entire program. Sorry this was my first day at SE and I'll definitely see the tour. Thanks again.

Comment: @JayParekh `malloc` will work.  However, since you are working in C++, please allow me to **strongly** recommend switching to `new` and `delete` instead of `malloc` and `free`.  Using `new`/`delete` means you don't have to typecast and the compiler can find more bugs for you.  Plus, you can't `malloc` a class,[1] so learning `new`/`delete` now will pave the way for when you start using object-oriented programming.          [Note 1] yes, C++ experts, I am ignoring placement `new` for purposes of this comment. Wouldn't you in my place? ;)